# How can add a line to block environment in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, xetex

I would like to define a block environment as illustrated in the figure in the link

[image]

I made this block using the code

```
\begin{block}{My title\\ \vspace{-1.25em} \line(1,0){312}}\vspace{-0.7em}

        teste
\end{block}
```

Does someone knows how to do that? BTW, how can I change the title font using XeLaTeX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally, `beamer` uses the shading `bmb@transition` to add some color between the title and the body parts of a block. You can redefine this shading to produce a solid color:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow]
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=blue!70!black,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=white}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareverticalshading{bmb@transition}{200cm}{%
  color(0pt)=(blue!70!black); color(2pt)=(blue!70!black)}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{My Title}
Test text.
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the code above, the line width will be equal to the block width. If one wants the rule width to equal the width of the text inside the block, a different approach is necessary; in this case, the [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package can be used with its `beamer` skin, to produce a block having the same specifications as a `beamer` block, and then one can easily add the rule with the desired specifications.

A little example, comparing both approaches: a standard `beamer` block (rule width=block width), and a Bblock produced with the help of `tcolorbox` (rule width=text width):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow]
\usetikzlibrary{shadings,shadows}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=blue!70!black,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=white}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareverticalshading{bmb@transition}{200cm}{%
  color(0pt)=(blue!70!black); color(2pt)=(blue!70!black)}
\makeatother

\newtcolorbox{Bblock}[2][]{
  beamer,
  equal height group=beamer,
  colback=white,
  colframe=white,
  coltitle=blue!70!black,
  fonttitle=\normalfont\large,
  oversize,
  overlay={
    \draw[blue!70!black,ultra thick] 
    ([xshift=6pt,yshift=-0.5\pgflinewidth]title.south west) --
    ([xshift=-6pt,yshift=-0.5\pgflinewidth]title.south east);},
  left=1mm,
  right=1mm,
  top=1mm,
  bottom=1mm,
  middle=1mm,
  fuzzy shadow={0.6ex}{-0.6ex}{1pt}{0.5pt}{black!80!white},
  #1,title=#2}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{beamer@color/.style={top color=white,bottom color=white}}
\makeatother

\newcommand\Text{%just for the example
Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo
vitae lacus tincidunt ultrices. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, con-
sectetuer adipiscing elit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer
tempus convallis augue. Etiam facilisis. Nunc elementum fermen-
tum wisi.}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{My Title}
\Text
\end{block}

\begin{Bblock}{My Title}
\Text
\end{Bblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Medina,

Since the line starts before the texts, isn't possible to use \noindent inside the block, in order to align the text and the line?

Comment: @Humberto The line begins where the block does; the line goes from the left end of the block to the right end of the block; on the other hand, `\noindent` has no effect here.

Comment: @Humberto having a line whose width equals the text width (instead of the block width) can be done, but requires a different approach. In some hours (I have to leave now) I can add this new approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the tcolorbox inner theme and then add a rule to it:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useinnertheme[shadow,rounded]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{
  titlerule=0.5mm,
  titlerule style=blue
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{Title}
    Test
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]